# Failed to reach implicit threshold of 2 sub-policies, required 1 remaining

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

`BAD_REQUEST -- Error authorizing update: Error validating DeltaSet: Policy for [Groups] /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 2 sub-policies, required 1 remaining`

It is the log of my error

So i have one organization (org1), then i add one more organization with 
peer channel join .... --cafile path/admin cert of org1

Then i need to add third organization (org3), but now (as i understand the log) it asking me a --cafile of org1 and org2

I need only org1 as an administrator of channel, so i need to add channel members providing a signature only of org1, not of all channel organizations

Comment: I am also facing this.

Comment: @A.K. to fix that we need to change the `mod_policy` to `ANY` in channel config. If you will understand how to change it and apply for the channel, please ping me here...

Comment: I did it and verified it in channel.tx by inspecting it but it is not working for me.

Comment: @A.K. Can you please share a gist with your commands and channel config file that you got at the result. 
Also would be good to see the logs of root CA (ca.yourdomain.com)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54111779/error-in-channel-creation-in-hyperledger-fabric-using-node-js  this is the question, i posted for it. I will add git there. please have a look. @Bogdan

Answer (score 2):

By default modification policy (mod_policy) for channel application is set to MAJORITY - so if you didn't specify it other way and you have 2 orgs already, you need both signatures.

Comment: Exactly, I already reached it out that by default `mod_policy` is `MAJORITY`, so now i want to set it to `ANY`, but not resolved it yet. 
Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52532399/how-to-change-channel-policy-in-hyperledger-fabric), I am trying to find out how to change `mod_policy`.

Thank you