# How to change channel policy in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have created network using Hyperledger Farbic. 
Crypto - certificates was created with configtxgen tool, 
So, i created channel tx with:

> configtxgen -profile SampleChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./config/SampleChannel.tx -channelID SampleChannel

So, by default Admins

```
"policies": {
"Admins": {
"mod_policy": "Admins",
"policy": {
  "type": 3,
  "value": {
    "rule": "MAJORITY",
    "sub_policy": "Admins"
  }
},
"version": "0"
}
```

How can I change `mod_policy` to

```
"policies": {
"Admins": {
"mod_policy": "Admins",
"policy": {
  "type": 3,
  "value": {
    "rule": "ANY", // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    "sub_policy": "Admins"
  }
},
"version": "0"
}
```

My next step is to

> configtxgen -profile SampleChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./config/SampleChannel.tx -channelID SampleChannel -asOrg Org1MSP

But how can I use manually changed SampleChannel.tx to apply it to network?

Thanks so much for help

Answer (score 2):

Policies are two Types

- Signature policies
- ImplicitMeta policies

**`Signature policies`**
These policies identify specific users who must sign in order for a policy to be satisfied.

```
For Example:
    Policies:
      MyPolicy:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: “Org1.Peer OR Org2.Peer”
```

**`ImplicitMeta policies`**
ImplicitMeta policies aggregate the result of policies deeper into the configuration hierarchy that are ultimately defined by Signature policies. They support default rules like “A majority of the organization admins”. These policies use a different but still very simple syntax as compared to Signature policies: `<ALL|ANY|MAJORITY> <sub_policy>`.

```
For example ANY Readers or MAJORITY Admins.
Policies:
  MyPolicy:
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
```

> Coming to your Answer: While creating the config.tx Please make below
>   changes

```
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
```

If you want more specific instead of NAY Writers and want to specify only particular organization Admins. Use below snippet

```
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1.admin')"
```