# Error in Channel Creation in Hyperledger Fabric using Node.js

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I am looking to setup a simple Hyperledger Fabric network without using docker and trying to create channel by following [this](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-channel-create.html) tutorial using Node.js.
Steps i performed:

1. Setup crypto-config.yaml and generated crypto-material (crypto-config)
2. Setup fabric-ca-server-config.yaml by updating `keyfile` & `certfile`. started CA server
3. Setup configtx.yaml by defining one orderer and one organization. Created genesis block and configuration transaction

Now by when i run above tutorial node.js code, i get error on order terminal & as response of node.js call:

> 2019-01-09 16:16:54.619 IST [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> INFO 007
>    Obtaining identity
>
> 2019-01-09 16:16:54.619 IST [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 008 [channel: firstchannel]
>
> Rejecting broadcast of config message from 127.0.0.1:44198 because of
>   error: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required
>   1 remaining: permission denied

I tried many changes and still getting same error. Same error also appear while creating channel through terminal using `./peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c firstchannel -f ./channel.tx`

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Aniket-Engg/865a9cadba925f2710e6e30ae7149e93) is my channel.tx converted in JSON.

How this can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it worked!
Actually in `orderer.yaml`, i set `LOG` to `DEBUG` and now i can see the problem in channel creation well descriptive.

There were multiple things which i needed to improve but main thing was that in `orderer.yaml`, `GenesisMethod` was set to `file`, so it was creating system channel and was looking the signature of the `OrdererMSP` admin. Changing `GenesisMethod` to `provisional` got channel creation worked.